# preventing cross site request forgery using cookie generated using javascript

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, csrf

I'm building  a site where i need to accept comment from user,
from my home.php i'm sending an ajax request(post) with values as comment text and element id to comment.php which checks session id and saves comment to  database,
i recently found (as i'm very new to web security) that i can submit a form from any website to this comment.php when there is my website running in other tab(as session id will be present).
To prevent cross site request forgery i'm using the following technique,
before sending ajax request i'm setting a cookie 'comment' with value as element id using

```
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; ";
```

in javascript and sending the ajax request.

In the comment.php file after checking the session id and comparing the element id value from both _POST[] and _COOKIE and if both are same i'm taking it as valid request and continuing.

My question here is, is this a proper way to prevent cross site request forgery or is there any logical hole in this which can still lead to CSRF or to any other vulnerabilities..?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following

[CSRF in PHP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard)

Please go through other parts of the website for complete details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a hidden `<input>` ?

When someone visits a comment page

- generate a unique ID `key`
- save `key` to `$_SESSION`
- set a hidden `<input>`s value to `key`

When someone submits a comment, compare `$_POST`'s copy of `key` with `$_SESSION`'s copy of `key`

- If they match, seems legit, accept comment **then remove** `key` from `$_SESSION`
- If they don't match, something went wrong

If the comment was successful, add "last_comment_time" (as int/whatever) to `$_SESSION`. Prevent new comments by this user whilst `now - "last_comment_time" < some_time_span`

Comment: i'm afraid i cannot do this, because there are many elements on the home.php page.consider someone willing to spam the site by commenting about his website or any product.
he will open home.php and see the "unique id key" and write php with a loop to submit a comment on every element on home.php page using that "unique id key" as hidden <input> in his post
this way he can post million comments with a single script.
just to avoid this i'm using the process which i mentioned(generate a cookie with the particular commented element id every time user comments, which will expire in 10 sec)

Comment: while commenting i got a doubt what if spammer tries to write million comments on a single element. it is possible even with my technique, to avoid that i decide to null the cookie in comment.php after it is compared with _post[]. this way he cannot comment more than one comment on a single element also.
I should thank you for this, as i may not have got that with out your comment(in which case i would have not commented and would have  not got that) :)

Comment: @MohanKrishna Clearing from `$_SESSION` tends to be much easier than clearing a cookie and requires them to re-load the comment page to do a second comment -> more effort. It is always a cat and mouse game, so just make it so they'd have to put in excessive effort to the point it's rare enough to not worry/deal with on a per-user basis.

Comment: @Mohan: No, you generate a new ID for each user for each visit to the page with the form. "Spamming" in order to guess a valid unique ID would be possible, but exceedingly unlikely in practice. Using a single hardcoded ID, on the other hand, is trivially easy to break.

Comment: @Mohan: If you want to disallow writing a million comments, then you need to disallow someone writing a million comments. That's unrelated to CSRF. No CSRF protection in the world prevents someone from writing something which uses your site in a valid way but in an automated fashion. For that you would need something like a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @BillyONeal sorry but may be you did not go through the comments.i stated a valid solution for  which you said is not possible, please  go through my comments again if you fell its worth  doing so, :)

Comment: @MohanKrishna Using cookies for anything more than a session reference isn't the fashion these days. Your solution requires more overhead, only works at specific moments in your _PHP_ script (before content sent), can still be implemented by an attacker client-side using _JavaScript_ (_JavaScript_ can read and write cookies) and won't stop successive comments if they're sent before _HEADERS RECEIVED_ from the first comment. A flag/check in _SESSION_  does not have these problems of _COOKIE_.

Comment: @PaulS. i'm not using httponly cookie, so it is not like it will work in specific moments(before content sent), as it can be modified on both client side and server side.Agreed attacker can alter it using javascript but only if there is a scope for XSS attack it is a different story, but site is safe from xss attacks, so it shouldn't be creating any problem,
(if it(non httponly cookie) can be modified in any other way other than with common well known XSS, please do let me know, which will help me)
still thank you for your suggestions :)